# How do I display a Milkshape model?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, monogame

I have a problem displaying a Milkshape model after I ported my game from XNA to Monogame (WP8.1). Have in mind, this model is loaded "externally" without using Content - hence it is not an "xnb" file, but original "ms3d" file. I don't think that it has something to do with my custom effects file, as it looks messed up under all available effects.

For actual rendering of Milkshape model, I'm using a library from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148034/Loading-and-rendering-Milkshape-d-models-with-ani

I'm reading the model in Monogame by passing a `Stream` (using `OpenStreamForReadAsync()`) in the library's method instead of using `File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open)` function.

Screen from XNA: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocYBv.png

Screen from Monogame WP8.1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcoST.png

The background on Monogame was just removed for tests, it's not an issue. To eliminate possible other sources of issues, I tried to render only this single model - but it looks still wrong: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q07Rl.png

Comment: Maybe the **four-year** old Codeproject lib is the problem?  Have you tried loading simple then progressively more complex shapes to test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by changing the custom vertex declaration to VertexPositionNormalTexture. Here's code:

```
        foreach (var milkshapeGroup in Groups)
        {
            milkshapeGroup.verticesPhone = null;
            var vertList = new List<VertexPositionNormalTexture>();
            foreach (var ver in milkshapeGroup.vertices)
            {
                vertList.Add(new VertexPositionNormalTexture(ver.Position, ver.Normal, ver.texCoord1));
            }
            milkshapeGroup.verticesPhone = vertList.ToArray();
        }
```